# Trigger macro when a formula in cells in a range gives one of two texts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to create a macro that calls another macro when a specific range of cells that contain formulas give an output of one of two specific strings.

The formula is `=IF(E15<=$G$5,"CHECK",IF(E15<=$F$5,"WARNING","OK"))`.

I want to trigger the macro every time there is an output "CHECK" or "WARNING". I want to trigger the macro every time the output is giving either of these two strings and not just once inside this range.

The range I want to look at and contains the formula is `F8:F38`.

I can find something like this

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("F8:F38").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Call email
End Sub
```

This is not working in case there is a formula instead of just a string.

Comment: What does this sentence exactly mean? *"I want to trigger the macro every time the output is giving these two strings and not just once inside this range."*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Worksheet.Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event, and a loop:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Me.Range("F8:F38")
        If cell.Value = "CHECK" Or cell.Value = "WARNING" Then
            Email ' no need for Call
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If you only want to `email` when the values in `F3:F38` have *changed*, then something like this:

In a regular module:

```
Public vals() As Variant ' public variable containing the 'old' values
```

In the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' populate vals when opening workbook
    vals = Me.Worksheets("Yourworksheetname").Range("F3:F38").Value
End Sub
```

In the sheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Me.Range("F8:F38")
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = counter + 1
        
        If cell.Value = "CHECK" Or cell.Value = "WARNING" Then
            ' check if the 'new' value is different from the 'old' one
            If cell.Value <> vals(counter, 1) Then 
                Email
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    vals = Me.Range("F8:F38").Value ' store the 'new' values 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How I can run the macro every time I change the value to CHECK or WARNING? For example if I change value in Column E to get a CHECK or WARNING, how can I trigger the email macro again?

Comment: Put the above code in the sheet code module? This is triggered when formulas are calculated.

Comment: Using the [WorksheetFunction.CountIfs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs) might be faster than looping if the range gets bigger any time.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough, and I am sorry for that! If I have already opened the file and change a value in column E and get a CHECK or WARNING then nothing happen. I want to trigger the macro every time I am into the file and the cell value in column F change.

Comment: Where did you put the above code? It should be in the sheet code module. Right click the worksheet tab, select View Code, and paste this in the module that opens.

Comment: @BigBen gotcha. You may also consider applying a `Worksheet Change` event that scans over the range of inputs that trigger a calculation change for your output cell.

Comment: Both, the `Worksheet_Calculate` and the `Worksheet_Change` event cannot do what the OP wants. The first one will trigger on calculate that means even if there is no change in CHECK/WARNING it will run and send a mail. And the `Change` event does not work because a change in `E` does not necessarily change CHECK/WARNING in F, there might be a silent change in `E` and still it triggers the mail. • So what the OP wants does not exist out of the box in Excel and can only be achieved by workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That what I was looking for!! 
 @BigBen I will consider your answer as the right one.

Comment: @BigBen Sure thank you.!

Comment: @Pro - good point, I've edited using the `Workbook_Open` event.